# How to make skin reacting to touch

Tags: materials, collision

When you punch someone, skin will deform, same if you squeez your leg or other body part. I want this effect, because i'm making animation concentrated on interaction between characters.
I tried to do this with soft body, but it didn't work well, less or more it felt like a jelly. Is there any way to do this alone, in ordinary conditions and PC that isn't nuclear reator? 
Wasn't able to find specific answer on the internet.

Comment: I'm too new to give any advice but does this seem helpful at all? 
https://www.blendernation.com/2015/01/28/p2design-tutorial-advanced-skin-deformation-in-blender/

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't the answer i'm looking for. It is made with shapekeys, is super useful in general and i will use them too, but it's not what i need : <

Comment: I understand. Well stick around hopefully someone will answer. Welcome Blender.SE btw :)

Comment: have you thought about adding bones on the part of your character that will be deformed? or using modifiers like Lattice or Meshdeform? I guess you first need to determine what is your storyboard: When and on what part of the body will the deformations happen? Then you will be able to find the solution that fits the best. That's just my opinion...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

You can achieve pretty good effect with **Soft Body**. I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but as for deforming skin in general this should be ok.

### Mesh:

Default **Sphere** for **Soft Body** and **Collision**. **Subdivision Surface** is added after (!) **Soft Body**.

[image: mesh]

### Soft Body:

For **Goal** you should select **Vertex Group** marked in previous screenshot or you can even paint **Weight** for this to mark which part should be affected.

Most important thing is to select **Stiff Quads** and set **Bending** > 0.5

[image: sb]

Comment: Thank you, this gif gives me hope that soft body can work pretty good, i will experiment a little more with it using your tips. It's hard tho, because of my old pc, but apperently I have to be patient.

Comment: @klufok keep base mesh pretty low poly and Soft Body shouldn't be to demanding and in this case will even look better. If your mesh will be more dense than you should set Bending to higher value but this setting will be hard for CPU.

Comment: I would probably add for anyone looking at this in future (v 2.91 currently) that for goal strength you want it slightly below the max. So if max is 1.0 you want it at 0.999 or something along those lines. Seems setting it to max effectively disables the soft body dynamics.