# Simple hair / clothes physics

Tags: rigging

I'm not very experienced with blender, but I'm learning so I can create models for my video games.

I want to create a SIMPLE (that's the keyword) parts of my model that will react to movement. For example, a ponytail that is not made of particles, but polygons which will bounce while walking.

Or very simple clothes (like the edge of the shorts moving with each step).

How would I do that? Soft body? Some kind of armature?
For performance / simplicity reasons, I don't want to use hair particles nor the dynamic clothes system.

Edit:
Another example could be springy parts of some object, like the antenna on a car.

Comment: One of them is probably duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74409/bending-a-pole-with-wind/74444#74444 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86471/how-to-make-grass-respond-to-an-object-hitting-them/86483#86483 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102176/how-to-make-skin-reacting-to-touch/102182#102182 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102259/how-to-have-multiple-soft-bodies-in-a-single-object/102291#102291 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102176/how-to-make-skin-reacting-to-touch/102182#102182

Comment: Thank you, I will check them all out when I'm free!